# iOS 5 , Xcode 4.2 and ProtoBuf

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile google protobuf protocol for using it in my iOS 5 project, but with no success yet... I found only one blog post about the topic [here](http://blog.saers.com/archives/2012/02/05/compile-protobuf-for-ios/comment-page-1/). But when I try this method I receive error:

```
h-3.2# make
make all-recursive
Making all in .
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am’.
Making all in src
protoc -I. –cpp_out=. google/protobuf/unittest.proto google/protobuf/unittest_empty.proto google/protobuf/unittest_import.proto google/protobuf/unittest_mset.proto google/protobuf/unittest_optimize_for.proto google/protobuf/unittest_embed_optimize_for.proto google/protobuf/unittest_custom_options.proto google/protobuf/unittest_lite.proto google/protobuf/unittest_import_lite.proto google/protobuf/unittest_lite_imports_nonlite.proto google/protobuf/unittest_no_generic_services.proto google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_test_bad_identifiers.proto
google/protobuf/unittest.proto:490:46: Expected number.
google/protobuf/unittest.proto:491:51: Expected number.
google/protobuf/unittest.proto:492:46: Expected number.
google/protobuf/unittest.proto:493:44: Expected number.
google/protobuf/unittest.proto:494:49: Expected number.
google/protobuf/unittest.proto:495:44: Expected number.
make[2]: *** [unittest_proto_middleman] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have worked old project with protobuf but it is created in xcode 3.x.
Is there a way or some tutorial how to use it in xcode 4.2 and armv7 architecture? 
I lose 2 days of my project time to research the problem and still no success... My project deadline is soon and I have no chance to proceed without this protobuf...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Objective-C protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers)?

Comment: Yes, I have try everything that I have found ... but no success protobuf with xcode 4.2 and iOS 5..

Comment: Well the build output that you posted in the question looks like google's official protobuf library. What happened when you tried using Cyrus Najmabadi's objective c implementation?

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://www.giraffe-games.com/using-protobuf-protocol-buffers-on-iphone-ios/) gives the instructions on how to compile the protobuf library with armv7, armv7s, i386 architectures for iOS. There is also a link in the blog post to download a precompiled iOS library for protobuf that works on the device as well as the simulator.